# Run MEF with ChannelFactory using plugins app.config

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mef, channelfactory

I have an appliction (Console) that runs on a timmer, this application uses MEF to check the plugins folder, each plugin is loaded correctly and runs fine.
The problem is that I am using Entity Framework database first in one of the plugins, I do not (Cannot) change the console application (base application).
I would like to call the plugins app.config and read this data from there.
I have read that the correct way to do this would be using channelfactory, but I have no idea how to impliment this. I asume that the Channelfactory goes here, somewhere .... if you could please help me out thanks

```
[Export(typeof(IMEFplugin))]
class ProgramStart : IMEFplugin
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "TemplateMEFService";
        }
    }
    private static bool Threadrunning;
    public void Do()
    {


       if (!Threadrunning)
        {
            try
            {

                Threadrunning = true;
                GetAppCommands RunMainClass = new GetAppCommands();
                {
                    try
                    {
                        RunMainClass.TaskForApp();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (RunMainClass != null)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(ex);

                        }

                    }
                    finally
                    {


                    }

                }
                Threadrunning = false;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                Threadrunning = false;
            }
            finally
            {
               // Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up");
                Threadrunning = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Isn't ChannelFactory for WCF services?